# Do unitarily equivalent normal operators always have same cyclic vectors?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, operator-theory

Let two normal operators A and B be unitarily equivalent, i.e. A = U*BU where U is unitary operator.

It follows that A and B have or do not have cyclic vectors at the same time, but does it follow that these vectors are the same?

It seems not, but I cannot create a counterexample.

Comment: Won't the cyclic vectors of $U^{-1}BU$ be just $U^{-1}v$ for all cyclic vectors $v$ of $B$?

Comment: So to create a counterexample, let $u$ and $v$ be unit vectors such that $u$ is a cyclic vector for $A$ while $v$ is not, let $U$ be a unitary so that $U u = v$, and let $B = U A U^*$.